# SonarQube - Jenkins - Code problem or a Timeout? This is the question

Tags: jenkins, automation, sonarqube, devops, sonarqube-scan

Everywhere I see examples like:

```
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
        def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
        if (qg.status != 'OK') {
            setBuildStatus ("${context}", "Sonarqube quality gate fail: ${qg.status}", 'FAILURE')
            error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
        } else {
            setBuildStatus ("${context}", "Sonarqube quality gate pass: ${qg.status}", 'SUCCESS')
        }
```

My question is what if SonarQube timeouts? I would like to have different notifications whether it gives a timeout or if code fails? What if it timeouts during the test? Sure I can make a simple http query before the quality gate, but if it fails during the quality gate?
Has anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a "timeout" block exited by passing the specified time, then enclose the "timeout" block in a try/catch block and check for "FlowInterruptedException".

If this is your original block:

```
timeout {
    ... do stuff
}
```

Change it to:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException;

try {
    timeout {
        ... do stuff
    }
}
catch (FlowInterruptedException ex) {
    println "Caught \"" + ex + "\" waiting for quality gate."
}
```

Comment: Can you give example wit FlowInterruptedException. Cause I'm not sure how can I check for that?

Comment: Updated answer.